# Homestead Laravel - Unable to create lockable file: /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/storage/framework/cache/data/ca

Tags: laravel, homestead

I just installed Homestead and Laravel is throwing an exception about file permissions. However I already add permission as 777 level, tried to change the folder ownership, and I am still getting the same error.
The folder ownership doesn't get changed, neither for root nor for www-data.

As I just said, I tried the suggestions about changing the file permissions and ownership of `bootstrap/cache` and `storage/logs/laravel.log`, but it is not working.

Exception

```bash
Exception: Unable to create lockable file: /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/storage/framework/cache/data/ca/4c/ca4c856c5905c536caed2f9104b57c207236dc77. Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location. in file /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php on line 73

#0 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php(43): Illuminate\Filesystem\LockableFile->createResource()
#1 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php(108): Illuminate\Filesystem\LockableFile->__construct()
#2 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(318): Illuminate\Cache\FileStore->add()
#3 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php(118): Illuminate\Cache\Repository->add()
#4 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(149): Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter->hit()
#5 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(118): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest()
#6 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(80): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()
#7 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle()
#8 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#9 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(797): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#10 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#11 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(740): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute()
#12 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(729): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#13 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch()
#14 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
#15 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/app/Http/Middleware/EnforceSecureConnection.php(22): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#16 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): App\Http\Middleware\EnforceSecureConnection->handle()
#17 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#18 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
#19 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#20 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#21 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
#22 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle()
#23 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#24 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#25 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#26 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#27 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#28 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors->handle()
#29 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#30 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle()
#31 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#32 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#33 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#34 /home/vagrant/codes/project-name/public/index.php(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle()
#35 {main}
```

- PHP v8.2
- Laravel Framework v10.10.1
- Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Homestead v14.3.0
- Vagrant 2.2.9
- VirtualBox 6.1.38